# How do I move all the data from NSMutableArray to NSArray with a key

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an array `NSMutableArray`. It contained objects from the XML file - `@"time"`. I need to move all records from `NSMutableArray` with key `@"time"` to `NSArray`. This is in order that would be based on the date on the calendar is highlighted markers. How can I implement it?

If I write the code:

```
NSDictionary *nItem = [rasp objectAtIndex:0]; //here instead of 0, you should put the number of elements in the array, but I do not get ((
NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[nItem objectForKey:@"time"], nil];
```

`NSMutableArray` is allocated only a first date from the array, index 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
NSMutableArray* mutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

for(NSDictionary* nItem in rasp)
{
    [mutable addObject:[nItem objectForKey:@"time"]];
}
NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutable];
```

Hope it helps!